# Node.js-Express-Strompath No CustomData after immediately after registration

Tags: node.js, express, npm, stormpath

I am having a strange error (at least in my opinion) after registering a user to stormpath via node/express using the Express-Stormpath module.

Just after registering I seem to have no access to customData in various routes for just the first user session. On registration I am creating and array for invoices

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
    ...,
    expandCustomData: true,
    postRegistrationHandler: function(account, req, res, next) {

        account.customData.invoices = [];
        account.save();

        next();
    }
}));
```

but then when I go to access them in my index route I get this error

```
router.get('/', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res){

    console.log(req.user.customData.invoices ); // undefined

     res.render('index', {
        title: 'Index'
     });
});
```

how ever if I kill my local and restart it I get

```
 console.log(req.user.customData.invoices ); // []
```

which is what i would like.

Can anyone shed some light into what i am doing incorrectly here?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening here is this: when you're inside of the `postRegistrationHandler` code -- customData won't be available automatically by default. The `postRegistrationHandler` is called *immediately* after registration before any of the helper functions have fun.

What you need to do to make your example work is first 'fetch' the customData from the Stormpath service.

Here's a working example:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  ...,
  expandCustomData: true,
  postRegistrationHandler: function(account, req, res, next) {
    account.getCustomData(function(err, data) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      data.invoices = [];
      data.save();
      next();
    });
  }
}));
```

The above issue is really unclear in the docs -- this is 100% my fault (*I'm the author of the library*) -- I'll get this fixed today =)

Comment: Cheers, I'll be making the update around lunch and will keep you posted. Thx again.